# xUnit Moq setup failed to detect the method when a object is passed in

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq, xunit, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm very new to unit test and moq. In my .net core 3.1 project I', using xUnit and Moq to write unit test. I have below scenario that I couldn't figure out why the moq can't detect my function.

I have configured my Unit test as below,

```
        VASTest t = new VASTest()
        {
            RecurringAndOneOffChargeID = 2
        };

        _dataserviceMock.Setup(x => x.CreateVASBillingRunRecurringChargesTest(t))
            .ReturnsAsync(() => true);

        _dataserviceMock.Setup(x => x.CreateVASBillingRunRecurringChargesTest(2))
            .ReturnsAsync(() => true);
```

In my test function I have blow two functions which I'm trying to moqup with above setup,

```
         var result1 = _VASBillingDataAccess.CreateVASBillingRunRecurringChargesTest(tvt).Result;
         var result2 = _VASBillingDataAccess.CreateVASBillingRunRecurringChargesTest(2).Result;
```

I have blow class in my models,

```
public class VASTest
{
    public int RecurringAndOneOffChargeID { get; set; }
}
```

when I'm running the unit test, result1 is always false, but result2 is always true.

Could you please give me some suggestion how to fix the result1?

Thank you.

Comment: If i change my setup with IsAny I get true for result1, but I actually want to verify that tvt object is correct as per my setup in the unit test. _dataserviceMock.Setup(x => x.CreateVASBillingRunRecurringChargesTest(It.IsAny<VASTest>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(() => true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your setup:

```
VASTest t = new VASTest()
{
  RecurringAndOneOffChargeID = 2
};

_dataserviceMock.Setup(x => x.CreateVASBillingRunRecurringChargesTest(t)).ReturnsAsync(() => true);
```

will only work if that instance of `VASTest` - `t` - is used in the SUT invocation, or you implement your own equals method for the `VASTest` class that can resolve if 2 instances of `VASTest` are equal to each other. If either of those are not the case then you're performing the equality check by reference and that will not be satisfied. Your other setup using the int (2) works as an int is a value type and an equality check is always done on the value iself.

I'd just do the following if I wasn't implementing `IEquatable<T>`:

```
_dataserviceMock.Setup(x => 
    x.CreateVASBillingRunRecurringChargesTest(
        It.Is<VASTest>(t => t.RecurringAndOneOffChargeID.Equals(2))))
    .ReturnsAsync(() => true);
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for your support. It is working now